# Artifacts in viewport. Recalculate Normals and Remove Double Verticles have no effect

Tags: artifacts

I feel stupid, but I don't know what to do. Bad topology? there is no triangles

[image: Wireframe]Wireframe

[image: Solidmode. X-ray is off.]Solidmode. X-ray is off.

[image]Render mode is ok, cycles

[image]artifacts

Comment: Could you upload your blend file using blend exchange? Link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: Try "Object - Shade Smooth" in Object Mode. Those aren't artifacts, it's just how the light reflects from the surface of your geometry, if your quads aren't completely flat.

Comment: This is my .blend file https://www.dropbox.com/s/qmj4mejb0qdbxmx/chair%21.blend1?dl=0 I cannot upload it by blend_exchange now

Comment: I actually can't seem to find out what happened to your mesh. But when I create a new scene and append all the objects from your blend file to the new scene; the artefacts are gone... (File>Append and import all items from the object folder inside your blend file)... Also, you uploaded the .blend1 file instead of the .blend file.